# How to have eslint enforce multiline if statements style

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there any eslint rule or plugins enforcing style for multiline if statements?

```
// Bad
if (a &&
    b) {
     // do stuff
}

// Good
if (
    a &&
    b
) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? It's been 5 years 

Comment: @Simon haha no, but since then there's been [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) which handles all my formatting concerns. It made my question unimportant, I highly recommend you giving it a go, and enforce it through eslint if you work with a team.